# I am not getting code assist for a particular type of object in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have class in one package. and I am creating an instance of this class in another class which is in different package. When i want to use any methods on this object, i can use ctrl+space for code assist which shows all reachable methods which i can use. But in this case it is not showing any, even public setters and getters. So wanted to know am I missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add the package to your build path. Look here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962